# Is there a microsoft-clr based architecture equivalent to java-osgi modular architecture?

Tags: java, .net, module, osgi

Is there a clear modular architecture pattern described for microsoft-clr based development?
example, one that defines how to allow plugging modules in to/out of a larger application - such as an application made up of a web-ui, service-layer and etl modules?

Comment: I think you should be more specific. What kind of modular architecture? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A widely accepted architecture that defines how to allow plugging modules in to/out of a larger application - example, an application made up of a web-ui, service-layer and etl modules

Comment: You might want to check out Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I had the same question and found this:  [OSGi.NET on CodePlex](http://osgi.codeplex.com/).  Since I have not used either Java OGSI or this .NET version I do not consider this a proper answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

simply, No, I could not find any projects/guidelines that suggest a modular architecture for .net applications